# Is there an algorithm to solve all soluble group word problems?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

What I mean is, is there an algorithm that given any finitely presented group with soluble word problem can solve the word problem on that group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is the Boone-Rogers theorem on unsolvability of the uniform word problem. It's actually mentioned in the Wikipedia article on the word problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind me asking, it says that there exists no "uniform partial algorithm" that solves the word problem for all finitely presented groups with soluble word problem, I can grok what "partial algorithm" means from the link, but what does the word "uniform" signify?

Comment: @user3 Honestly I'm not an expert on this, I found your question interesting and looked up the answer on Wikipedia. I would guess uniform just means it works for everything.

Comment: That's correct, uniform means it should work across a class of groups (in this case the finitely presented groups with solvable word problem), so that the presentation is part of the input to the algorithm.